# SQL Server 2008 R2 connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

HI people.

I had SQL Server 2005 on Windows XP 32bit and just used this connection string

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=GroupALD; Integrated Security=True"
```

Now I have Windows 7 64bit and SQL Server 2008 R2 I'm trying to connect database with same string but its shows this error

> Cannot open database "GroupALD" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'lester\les'.

Can somebody help me?

I'm using C# and Winforms

Comment: Sounds like this is not a connection string issue but rather a permission setting in the database itself. Otherwise, http://www.connectionstrings.com is a great resource for various connection string examples.

Comment: Change Server to Data Source; otherwise it is a permission issue

Comment: @Carnotauraus: that's **definitely** **NOT** the problem. I prefer `server=` and `database=` - seems much clearer (than `data source=` and `initial catalog=`) - and those settings work just fine every day in production...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008):

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: i have express edition. when im using SSPI its shows such error A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear:

> Cannot open database "GroupALD"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed.
>   **Login failed for user 'lester\les'**.

Your user doesn't have a valid login on your new database - it's not a connection-string related issue - you need to create a login for `lester\les` on your new server and create a user in the `GroupALD` database for that login.

See : [how to create a SQL Server Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to your express edition using SQL Server Management Studio of R2 ?

One workaround i can suggest is to export the database from express to R2 if you can connect to R2 using your connection string .

Comment: YES i connecting with menagment studio without problems. but my app shows errors

Comment: @user525717: are you connecting with your user `lester\les` ?? Or with `sa` or your integrated Windows account??